# How to get native type of a model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to dynamically inspect the python types of all the fields within my models in an app, that is, given that I have:

```
class MyModel(model.Model):
    field1 = model.CharField(max_length=20)
    field2 = modelf.IntegerField()
    ...
    fieldn = models.BooleanField()
```

I need to accomplish something like:

```
>>> for field in MyModel._meta.fields:
•••     field.type
•••
<type 'str'>
<type 'int'>
...
```

obviously `field.type` is something that does not exist, but I need to retrieve the built-in type the model is supposed to accept when the model is created/updated. ForeignKeys and M2M are a special case that can be ignored for this question.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you explain why you need this? Maybe if we knew what you were trying to do, we could figure out a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, `Field`s do not contain such information. The `to_python` method is used to convert values into the expected Python data type, and it's free to return whatever it likes.

You can build a type map yourself, obviously limited to field types you know about:

```
FIELD_PYTHON_TYPES = {
    'AutoField': int,
    'BooleanField': bool,
    'CharField': unicode,
    'DateField': datetime.date,
    'DateTimeField': datetime.datetime,
    'DecimalField': decimal.Decimal,
    'FloatField': float,
    'IntegerField': int,
    'BigIntegerField': int,
     ... # etc.
}
```

and look up types from it with `get_internal_type`:

```
for field in MyModel._meta.fields:
    FIELD_PYTHON_TYPES[field.get_internal_type()]
```

But even, for example, built-in `NullBooleanField` can use two types (`bool` and `NoneType`), so it's far from a general solution.